# Serverless provider.environment variables not available in custom

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to reference variables in `self:provider.environment` in my custom variables block; however, I get the following warning:

```
Serverless Warning --------------------------------------

  A valid service attribute to satisfy the declaration 
  'self:provider.environment.myVar' could not be found.
```

We are using serverless 1.28.0, here's a sample config:

```
service: testing-vars
provider:
  region: 'us-west-2'
  environment:
    myVar: ${env:myVar, self:custom.dotenv.myVar}
custom:
  refToAbove: ${self:provider.environment.myVar}
...
```

I would like to reference the provider.environment vars in my custom block.

Comment: Are you sure that either `env:myVar` or `self:custom.dotenv.myVar` are defined? It is hard to tell what the problem is without the rest of the definition.

Comment: I found that this was due to a plugin not handling vars properly, so those were indeed not defined at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due a plugin not handling variables properly and has been fixed.

Comment: What plugin? I am having the same problem.